# Queue implementation with Generics in Java

Tags: java, generics, queue

trying to make an immutable queue and performing standard queue operations on it,using generics.the problem is i dont know much about generics :( please bear with me about the flow and structure of the code

so far i have

```
import java.lang.*;
import.java.util.*;
import java.util.NoSuchElementException;

public class ImmutableQueue<E>
{
  private final List<E> elmnts;

   public ImmutableQueue(List<E> elmnts) 
    {
     this.elmnts = elmnts;
     return elmnts.newInstance(); 
    }

  public ImmutableQueue() 
  {
    elmnts = new LinkedList<E>();
  }

 public ImmutableQueue<E> enqueue(E e)
 {
    if(e.equals("null"))
      throws IllegalArgumentException;

    List<E> copy = new LinkedList<E>(elmnts);
    copy.add(elmnts);
    copy.addlast(e);
    Iterator iterator = copy.iterator();
    while(iterator.hasNext())
     {
       Object prnt = itr.next();
       System.out.println(prnt+" ");
     }
   }

  public ImmutableQueue<E> dequeue()
  {
     if (elmnts.size() == 0) 
     {
      throw new NoSuchElementException();
     }

    List<E> copy = new LinkedList<E>(elmnts);
    copy.add(elmnts);
    copy.remove(0);

    Iterator iterator = copy.iterator();
     while(iterator.hasNext())
      {
       Object prnt = itr.next();
       System.out.println(prnt+" ");
      }
  } 

  public E peek()
  {
    String fsel=elmnts.get(0);
    System.out.println("First Element in the Queue is "+fsel);
    return null;
   }

  public int size()
  {
    int size=0;
    Iterator iterator = elmnts.iterator();
     while(iterator.hasNext())
     {
      size++; 
     }
    return size;
  }


     public static void main(String [] arg)
     {
        int a;
        BufferedReader br=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in)) ;

        ImmutableQueue<E> imqu=new LinkedList<E>();

        System.out.println("Create Queue/Add Elements to Queue ? ('N' or 'n' to stop)");
       <E> e=br.readLine();

       while(e!='n' || e!='N')
       {  
        imqu.insert(e);
       }

      System.out.println(":: Queue Operations ::");
      System.out.println("\n\n\n21.Enqueue\n2.Dequeue\n3.Peek\n4.size");

      a=Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());
      System.out.println("Choice"+a); 

    switch(a)
    {
     case 1: System.out.println("Element to be Enqueued : ");
             <E> el=br.readLine();
             imqu.enqueue(E el);
             break;

     case 2: imqu.dequeue();
             break;

     case 3: imqu.peek();
             break;

     case 4: int sz=imqu.size();
             System.out.println("Size of the queue is"+sz);
             break;

     default: System.out.println("Bad Choice");

    }
 }
}
```

thanks

Comment: Can you add more information about what you need: code review? bug tracking?

Comment: `return` in a ctor??

Comment: @smagnan bug tracking,i dont know how to return and send argument to and from generics

Comment: @Fildor sorry i dont quite understand you,"ctor" ?

Comment: Not clear about what you need. Looking at the code, there are couple of things - 1) there is a return statement in constructor which is not required  2) While enqueue() you have to take a copy of the object, add new element into it and return the copy of the queue (Actually the return statement is missing). 3) Again for dequeue, you have to return the copy of the queue after removing the first entry. 4) For size, you no need to iterate the list, just list.size will do

Comment: Sorry "ctor" = "Constructor". In the one taking a list Parameter. You return something.

Comment: @LoganathanMohanraj so  there is no return required in the constructor,right?....will tweak that thanks...but what if i want to copy the list in the enqueue/dequeue functions and display the list there,for i am not making changes to the original queue,will that okay to do ? ....list.size()...thanks again...:)

Comment: @Fildor yeah i thought that maybe to create an instance i have to do that,saw a couple of exams over the net...but i think that isnt so...but how do i fix that,i mean the way i wrote the code for object instantiation,is that okay ?

Comment: You' ll have to make a new (local) instance of the type of the parameter first, then copy the parameter's elements to that new instance and then set the instance variable holding the list to the newly created one and you're done. No need to return anything.

Comment: @Fildor okay.....but if i remove the overloaded constructor,the default will create the objects and from thereon other functions can use it and make copies...no ?

Comment: Not quite sure what you mean ...

Comment: @Fildor i meant is the constructor (overloaded one) required or not,coz i was really confused with what you meant about copying to local and then instance,were you saying about constructors or functions ? ....can you give me an example as to what you suggest

Answer (score 1):

I have done some change in the code that you have posted. This is how an immutable queue should look like. Immutable objects won't do any changes on it rather it will take a copy of the object, manipulates it and returns the same. String class in java is one such example.

```
import java.util.LinkedList;
import java.util.List;

public class ImmutableQueue<T> {

    private List<T> immuatableQ = null;

    public ImmutableQueue() {
        this.immuatableQ = new LinkedList<T>();
    }

    public ImmutableQueue(List<T> immutableQ) {
        this();
        if (immutableQ != null) {
            this.immuatableQ.addAll(immutableQ);
        }
    }

    public ImmutableQueue<T> enqueue(T newItem) {
        List<T> copyQ = new LinkedList<T>(this.immuatableQ);
        copyQ.add(newItem);

        return new ImmutableQueue<T>(copyQ);
    }

    public ImmutableQueue<T> dequeue() {
        List<T> copyQ = new LinkedList<T>(this.immuatableQ);
        copyQ.remove(0);

        return new ImmutableQueue<T>(copyQ);
    }

    public T peek() {
        return this.immuatableQ.get(0);
    }

    public int size() {
        return this.immuatableQ.size();
    }

    public boolean isEmpty() {
        return this.immuatableQ.size() == 0;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Look at this example implementation of Queue using Generis in Java. [java queue implemenation](http://algs4.cs.princeton.edu/43mst/Queue.java.html) You can read about Java Generics here [Java Generics](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/)